# Travis: don't clone in some jobs

Tags: git, travis-ci

I'm using a pipeline that goes in two steps:

1. from a git working directory, build a tarball and publish it (one job)
2. fetch the tarball and test it (many jobs)

Step 2 does not need the repository at all, it's a complete waste of ressources to check it out (in addition it has submodules, and some of them are very large).  How can I prevent Travis' initial git clone in my test jobs?

Comment: How would CI get your `.travis.yml` without cloning?

Comment: You have several options to customize how travis uses git in the [doc](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/customizing-the-build/), more specifically Git clone depth, git sparse chekcout and git submodules.

Comment: @phd Of course I don't know how Travis is implemented, but the `.travis.yml` has to be read and processed before running the rest.  The matrix must be interpreted and jobs assigned, etc.  So I very much doubt that the `.travis.yml` is actually needed on the slave/runner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have contacted Travis, and they answered favorably to my request: it is now possible to avoid all git costs with

```
git:
  clone: false
```

See [the Travis documentation about it](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/customizing-the-build/#disabling-git-clone), or look for "Disabling git clone" in their [history of changes](https://changelog.travis-ci.com).

The way I use this feature is:

```
git:
  clone: false

stages:
  - compile
  - test

jobs:
  include:
    - stage: "compile"
      git:
        clone: true
      ...

    - name: "GCC 7 -O3"
      stage: test
      ...

    - name: "Clang 7 libc++"
      stage: test
      ...

    - name: "ICC"
      stage: test
      # We need the build-aux/install-icc.sh script.
      git:
        clone: true
        submodules: false
        depth: 1
      ...
```